# How to monitor CPU/memory usage of a single process?

Tags: shell, process, monitoring, top

I would like to monitor one process's memory / cpu usage in real time. Similar to `top` but targeted at only one process, preferably with a history graph of some sort.

Comment: What memory statistics do you want? There are lots of them.

Comment: Memory usage over a given time frame, current usage, maximum usage, average.

Comment: Multiple solutions all good.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

On Linux, `top` actually supports focusing on a single process, although it naturally doesn't have a history graph:

```
top -p PID
```

This is also available on Mac OS X with a different syntax:

```
top -pid PID
```

Comment: And since you may not want to look up the PID every time, try something like `top -p \`pgrep -f /usr/bin/kvm\``.

Comment: I use Cacti to monitor some individual processes, but installing a full blown Cacti installation sounds too complex for the simple situation asked here.

Comment: @Stefan: I'm assuming I would have to run that remotely?

Comment: @Josh : Yes you would need to run Cacti (Which requires MySQL, Apache and few other packages) on another server. On most distros, it's pretty simple to install using Yum or apt-get.

Comment: @Stefan if you want to to check remotly you can do ssh@remotehost 'top -p PID > ~`hostname`_pid.txt; exit'and

Comment: There is also the `pidof` utility, which proves useful combined with this. `top -p $(pidof firefox | tr ' ' ',')`, using `tr` to turn spaces into commas.

Answer (score 198):

## Procpath

2020 update (Linux/procfs-only). Returning to the problem of process analysis frequently enough and not being satisfied with the solutions I described below originally, I decided to write [my own](https://pypi.org/project/Procpath/). It's a pure-Python CLI package including its couple of dependencies (no heavy Matplotlib), can potentially plot many metrics from procfs, JSONPath queries to the process tree, has basic decimation/aggregation (Ramer-Douglas-Peucker and moving average), filtering by time ranges and PIDs, and a couple of other things.

```
pip3 install --user procpath
```

Here's an example with Firefox. This records all processes with "firefox" in their `cmdline` (query by a PID would look like `'$..children[?(@.stat.pid == 42)]'`) 120 times one time per second.

```
procpath record -i 1 -r 120 -d ff.sqlite '$..children[?("firefox" in @.cmdline)]'
```

Plotting RSS and CPU usage of a single process (or several) out of all recorded would look like:

```
procpath plot -d ff.sqlite -q cpu -p 123 -f cpu.svg
procpath plot -d ff.sqlite -q rss -p 123 -f rss.svg
```

Charts look like this (they are actually interactive Pygal SVGs):

[image: RSS]
[image: CPU]

## psrecord

The following addresses *history graph of some sort*. Python [`psrecord`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psrecord) package does exactly this.

```
pip install psrecord                             # local user install
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib python-tk # for plotting; or via pip
```

For single process it's the following (stopped by <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>):

```
psrecord $(pgrep proc-name1) --interval 1 --plot plot1.png
```

For several processes the following script is helpful to synchronise the charts:

```
#!/bin/bash    
psrecord $(pgrep proc-name1) --interval 1 --duration 60 --plot plot1.png &
P1=$!
psrecord $(pgrep proc-name2) --interval 1 --duration 60 --plot plot2.png &
P2=$!
wait $P1 $P2
echo 'Done'
```

Charts look like:
[image: psrecord example]

## memory_profiler

The [package](https://pypi.org/project/memory_profiler/) provides RSS-only sampling (plus some Python-specific options). It can also record process with its children processes (see `mprof --help`).

```
pip install memory_profiler
mprof run /path/to/executable
mprof plot
```

By default this pops up a Tkinter-based (`python-tk` may be needed) chart explorer which can be exported:

[image: mprof]

## graphite-stack & statsd

It may seem an overkill for a simple one-off test, but for something like a several-day debugging it's, for sure, reasonable. A handy all-in-one [`raintank/graphite-stack`](https://hub.docker.com/r/raintank/graphite-stack/) (from Grafana's authors) image and [`psutil`](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) and [`statsd`](https://pypi.org/project/statsd/) client. [`procmon.py`](https://gist.github.com/saaj/d09ed8a5ab71bcc6e080a9566137484b) provides an implementation.

```
$ docker run --rm -p 8080:3000 -p 8125:8125/udp raintank/graphite-stack
```

Then in another terminal, after starting target process:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-statsd python-psutil # or via pip
$ python procmon.py -s localhost -f chromium -r 'chromium.*'
```

Then opening Grafana at http://localhost:8080, authentication as `admin:admin`, setting up datasource https://localhost, you can plot a chart like:

[image: grafana chart]

## graphite-stack & telegraf

Instead of Python script sending the metrics to Statsd, [`telegraf`](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/releases) (and `procstat` input plugin) can be used to send the metrics to Graphite directly.

Minimal `telegraf` configuration looks like:

```
[agent]
  interval = "1s"

[[outputs.graphite]]
  servers = ["localhost:2003"]
  prefix = "testprfx"

[[inputs.procstat]]
  pid_file = "/path/to/file/with.pid"
```

Then run line `telegraf --config minconf.conf`. Grafana part is the same, except metrics names.

## pidstat

`pidstat` (part of `sysstat` package) can produce output that can be easily parsed. It's useful in case when you need extra metrics from the process(es), e.g. most useful 3 groups (CPU, memory and disk) contain: `%usr`, `%system`, `%guest`, `%CPU`, `minflt/s`, `majflt/s`, `VSZ`, `RSS`, `%MEM`, `kB_rd/s`, `kB_wr/s`, `kB_ccwr/s`. I described it in [a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59182595/2072035).

Comment: pgrep systemd is giving multiple lines of output, and thus bugs the psrecord, what should be done? I just want to test with any process.

Comment: @EralpB `pgrep --help` to the rescue. There's at least `--newest` and `--oldest`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it actually gives a memory usage history plot. Note for the psrecord method, `Ctrl+C` on the psrecord process just quits without saving a plot, you need to end the process-under-test.

Comment: `psrecord` worked well, thank you. To get it to work on a server without a GUI (X11) I had to configure `matplotlibrc` as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605654/3018750

Comment: A simple one-liner if you want to run a command and profile it with `psrecord` right away: `my-command & psrecord $! --interval 1 --plot plot1.png`. `$!` returns the PID of the last executed command, so you don't need to `pgrep`. And using a single `&` runs `my-command` detached, meaning that the shell won't wait for it to finish before running `psrecord`.

Comment: How can i monitor specific thread of a process? I have passed id of thread as argument of `psrecord` but it plotted cpu usage of process instead of specified thread!

Answer (score 80):

**[`htop`](http://htop.sourceforge.net)** is a great replacement to `top`. It has… Colors! Simple keyboard shortcuts! Scroll the list using the arrow keys! Kill a process without leaving and without taking note of the PID! Mark multiple processes and kill them all!

Among all the features, the manpage says you can press <kbd>F</kbd> to *follow* a process.

Really, you should try `htop`. I never started `top` again, after the first time I used `htop`.

Display a single process:

```
htop -p PID
```

Comment: +1 for htop. This is one of the first program I install on a new system. It makes my life much easier. The tree view is also very handy.

Comment: `top` also has colors. Press `z`.

Comment: You're right! `top` has colors! Too bad its colors are quite useless, specially when compared to `htop` (which fades other users processes and highlights the program basename).

Comment: top can also kill processes without leaving. Just hit k.

Comment: And `htop -p PID` will work too, just like the example given by @Michael Mrozek.

Comment: Then only reason to use top, is because htop is not available or can't be installed. That is why htop was created, to provide much more features.

Answer (score 14):

Using `top` and `awk` one could easily create e.g. a comma separated log of %CPU (`$9`) + %MEM (`$10`) usage that can later be fed into any statistics and graphing tool.

```
top -b -d $delay -p $pid | awk -v OFS="," '$1+0>0 {
print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),$1,$NF,$9,$10; fflush() }'
```

Output will be like

```
2019-03-26 17:43:47,2991,firefox,13.0,5.2
2019-03-26 17:43:48,2991,firefox,4.0,5.2
2019-03-26 17:43:49,2991,firefox,64.0,5.3
2019-03-26 17:43:50,2991,firefox,71.3,5.4
2019-03-26 17:43:51,2991,firefox,67.0,5.4
```

This won't give good results for large `$delay`, though, because the printed timestamp is actually `$delay` behind due to how `top`'s output works. Without going into too much detail, 1 simple way around this is to log the time provided by `top`:

```
top -b -d $delay -p $pid | awk -v OFS="," '$1=="top"{ time=$3 }
$1+0>0 { print time,$1,$NF,$9,$10; fflush() }'
```

Then the timestamp is accurate, but output will still be delayed by `$delay`.

Answer (score 13):

I'm a bit late here but I'll share my command line trick using just the default `ps`

```
WATCHED_PID=$({ command_to_profile >log.stdout 2>log.stderr & } && echo $!);
while ps -p $WATCHED_PID --no-headers --format "etime pid %cpu %mem rss"; do 
   sleep 1 
done
```

I use this as a one-liner. Here the first line fires the command and stores the PID in the variable. Then ps will print the elapsed time, the PID the percent CPU using, the percent memory, and the RSS memory. You can add other fields as well.

As soon as the process ends, the `ps` command won't return "success" and the `while` loop will end.

You can ignore the first line if the PID you want to profile is already running. Just place the desired id in the variable.

You'll get an output like this:

```
  00:00  7805  0.0  0.0  2784
  00:01  7805 99.0  0.8 63876
  00:02  7805 99.5  1.3 104532
  00:03  7805  100  1.6 129876
  00:04  7805  100  2.1 170796
  00:05  7805  100  2.9 234984
  00:06  7805  100  3.7 297552
  00:07  7805  100  4.0 319464
  00:08  7805  100  4.2 337680
  00:09  7805  100  4.5 358800
  00:10  7805  100  4.7 371736
  ....
```

Answer (score 11):

### [`pidstat`](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/)

Show CPU statistics at a 2-second interval for 2 times, of PID 7994:

```bash
pidstat -p 7994 2 2

03:54:43 PM   UID       PID    %usr %system  %guest    %CPU   CPU  Command
03:54:45 PM     0      7994    1.50    1.50    0.00    3.00     1  AliYunDun
03:54:47 PM     0      7994    1.00    1.00    0.00    2.00     0  AliYunDun
```

More:

```bash
# Show page faults and memory utilization:
pidstat -r

# Show input/output usage per process id:
pidstat -d

# Show information on a specific PID:
pidstat -p PID

# Show memory statistics for all processes whose command name include "fox" or "bird":
pidstat -C "fox|bird" -r -p ALL
```

Answer (score 10):

To use that information on a script you can do this:

calcPercCpu.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
nPid=$1;
nTimes=10; # customize it
delay=0.1; # customize it
strCalc=`top -d $delay -b -n $nTimes -p $nPid \
  |grep $nPid \
  |sed -r -e "s;\s\s*; ;g" -e "s;^ *;;" \
  |cut -d' ' -f9 \
  |tr '\n' '+' \
  |sed -r -e "s;(.*)[+]$;\1;" -e "s/.*/scale=2;(&)\/$nTimes/"`;
nPercCpu=`echo "$strCalc" |bc -l`
echo $nPercCpu
```

use like: `calcPercCpu.sh 1234` where 1234 is the pid

For the specified $nPid, it will measure the **average** of 10 snapshots of the cpu usage in a whole of 1 second (delay of 0.1s each * nTimes=10); that provides a good and fast accurate result of what is happening in the very moment.

Tweak the variables to your needs.

Comment: Uhm, 10 processes to monitor the cpu usage of 1?

Comment: @xebeche "it will measure the **average** of 10 snapshots" "nTimes=10; # **customize** it" :)

Comment: I meant I don't like the fact that you call 10 processes to retrieve 1 number (`$nPercCpu`): shell, top, grep, sed, cut ... bc. Many if not all of these you could for instance merge into 1 Sed or Awk script.

Comment: @xebeche cool, feel free to edit adding a better command to the existing one (as an alternative), you got my curiosity :)

Comment: I've added [my own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508799/13746). BTW, note that there is no point in calculating an average because `top`'s output **is** an average over `$delay`. Cf. [How to calculate the CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424556/196133)

Answer (score 5):

I normally use following two :

1. [HP caliper](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801/?ciid=2908852bcbe02110852bcbe02110275d6e10RCRD)  : its very good tool for monitoring processes it you can check call graph and other low level information also. But please note its free only for personal use.
2. [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) : a collection of tools for managing UNIX services

Comment: I used daemontools for years. It's great as a supervisor/watchdog for other processes. How does it help you monitor CPU/memory usage for one process?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a cut-down Linux distribution where  top does not have per process (-p) option or related options, you can parse the output of the top command for your process name to get the CPU usage  information per process.

```
while true;  do top -bn1 | awk '/your_process_name/ {print  $8}' ; sleep 1; done
```

8 represents the CPU usage per process in the  output of the top command  in my embedded Linux distribution

Comment: I found this usefull as it track process name not pid, as for something like fail2ban-client the pid changes each time it runs, i had to change column $8 to $9

Answer (score 4):

**Launch a program and monitor it**

This form is useful if you want to benchmark an executable easily:

```
topp() (
  if [ -n "$O" ]; then
    $* &
  else
    $* &>/dev/null &
  fi
  pid="$!"
  trap "kill $pid" SIGINT
  o='%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss'
  printf '%s\n' "$o"
  i=0
  while s="$(ps --no-headers -o "$o" -p "$pid")"; do
    printf "$i $s\n"
    i=$(($i + 1))
    sleep "${T:-0.1}"
  done
)
```

Usage:

```
topp ./myprog arg1 arg2
```

Sample output:

```
%cpu,%mem,vsz
0  0.0  0.0 177584
1  0.0  0.1 588024
2  0.0  0.1 607084
3  0.0  0.2 637248
4  0.0  0.2 641692
5 68.0  0.2 637904
6 80.0  0.2 642832
```

where vsz is the total memory usage in KiB, e.g. the above had about 600MiB usage.

If your program finishes, the loop stops and we exit `topp`.

Alternatively, if you git Ctrl + C, the program also stops due to the `trap`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360201/how-do-i-kill-background-processes-jobs-when-my-shell-script-exits

The options are:

- `T=0.5 topp ./myprog`: change poll interval
- `O=1 topp ./myprog`: don't hide program stdout/stderr. This can be useful to help correlate at which point memory usage bursts with stdout.

**`ps` vs `top` on instantaneous CPU% usage**

Note that the CPU usage given by `ps` above is not "instantaneous", but rather the average over the processes' lifetime as mentioned at: [Top and ps not showing the same cpu result](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58539/top-and-ps-not-showing-the-same-cpu-result)

That thread as well as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332861/how-can-i-determine-the-current-cpu-utilization-from-the-shell/1332955#1332955 suggest that the Linux kernel does not store any more intermediate usage statistics, so the only way to do that would be to poll and calculate for the previous period, which is what `top` does.

We could therefore use `top -n1` instead of `ps` if we wanted that:

```
toppp() (
  $* &>/dev/null &
  pid="$!"
  trap exit SIGINT
  i=1
  top -b n1 -d "${T:-0.1}" -n1 -p "$pid"
  while true; do top -b n1 -d "${T:-0.1}" -n1 -p "$pid"  | tail -1; printf "$i "; i=$(($i + 1)); done
)
```

as mentioned e.g. at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62421136/895245 which produces output of type:

```
top - 17:36:59 up  9:25, 12 users,  load average: 0.32, 1.75, 2.21
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 13.4 us,  2.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 84.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  31893.7 total,  13904.3 free,  15139.8 used,   2849.7 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.  16005.5 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 706287 ciro      20   0  590436  40352  20568 R 106.7   0.1   0:00.16 node
 706287 ciro      20   0  607060  57172  21340 R 126.7   0.2   0:00.35 node
1  706287 ciro      20   0  642008  80276  21812 R 113.3   0.2   0:00.52 node
2  706287 ciro      20   0  641676  93108  21812 R 113.3   0.3   0:00.70 node
3  706287 ciro      20   0  647892  99956  21812 R 106.7   0.3   0:00.87 node
4  706287 ciro      20   0  655980 109564  21812 R 140.0   0.3   0:01.09 node
```

Some related threads:

- how to run `top` just once (`-b -n1`)

  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/484510/how-to-run-top-command-1-time-and-exit
  - [How to stream top snapshot into file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60328/how-to-stream-top-snapshot-into-file) asks about
- how to remove the headers from `top`: no one has a better solution so we just `tail` it:

  - [How to remove 'top' command's header?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471072/how-to-remove-top-commands-header)
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995380/how-to-suppress-the-general-information-for-top-command

My only problems with this is that `top` is not as nice for interactive usage:

- Ctrl + C does not exit the above command, not sure why `trap exit` is not working as it does with `ps`. I have to kill the command `Ctrl + \`, and then that does not kill the process itself which continues to run on the background, which means that if it is an infinite loop like a server, I have to `ps aux` and then kill it.
- the not exit automatically when the benchmarked program exits

Maybe someone more shell savvy than me can find a solution for those.

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221555/retrieve-cpu-usage-and-memory-usage-of-a-single-process-on-linux
- [How to monitor CPU/memory usage of a single process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554/how-to-monitor-cpu-memory-usage-of-a-single-process)

Tested on Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: This is misleading since the `ps` command doesn't show the current cpu usage of the process, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58539/top-and-ps-not-showing-the-same-cpu-result.

Comment: The issue with the `top -bn1` %CPU value is that it is very inaccurate. For that, `pidstat` is much better, but unfortunately, with this utility, it is not possible to output both the %CPU and RSS on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

If you know process name you can use

```
top -p $(pidof <process_name>)
```

Comment: That's pretty much what the accepted answer, from years ago, and its first comment say.

Answer (score 2):

Not enough reputation to comment, but for psrecord you can also call it directly, in a programmatic way, directly in Python:

```
from psrecord.main import monitor
monitor(<pid number>, logfile = "./test.log", plot="./fig.png", include_children=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

MacOS solution to create the following graph

[image: plotted data of process cpu consumption]

```
# Install dependencies
brew install gnuplot libmagic 

# Sample process. Replace 1234 with process ID
while :;do ps -p 1234 -o %cpu= >> procdata.txt;sleep 1;done

# Plot
gnuplot<<<'set term png;set output "procplot.png";plot "procdata.txt" with boxes'
```

Answer (score 2):

Monitoring memory usage is something I frequently need when testing C++ apps. I used the solutions already provided in the previous answers and I also wrote a little app for myself and I made it available here in case anyone else needs it in the future: https://github.com/carlonluca/procweb.

It is a binary written in Rust (there is also a version written in Qt [in the repo](https://github.com/carlonluca/procweb/tree/master/procweb-qt)) that monitors a process by sampling RAM/IO/CPU etc... The binary also starts a web server to let the user inspect data:

[image: procweb]

The binary stores all the samples, the chart range and scale can be tuned, you can download a CSV and the chart itself. Data is kept in memory until the sampler process is killed. The page can be freely refreshed without losing data.

Can be installed through Cargo: `cargo install procweb-rust`. Static binaries for x64, arm64 and armhf can also be downloaded from the GitHub repo.

More info [here](https://bugfreeblog.duckdns.org/2023/03/monitoring-a-process-vitals.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you need the averages for a period of time of a specific process, try the accumulative -c option of top:

```
top -c a -pid PID
```

"-c a" found in top for Mac 10.8.5.

For Scientific Linux, the option is -S, that can be set interactively.

Comment: You'll likely want to add further details around which version(s) of `top` actually provide this feature. My version on Fedora 19 does not. Same too on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: You're right!, I was so happy of having found something useful, I forgot I was in my mac at home.

Comment: This is the approach I prefer and it works

Answer (score 0):

## `bash` script tracking resources of a process

Here some example script, which might come handy. Works just with `ps` and `top`. As an example process I chose a python script (high cpu utilization, 3 seconds break, high cpu utilization). You get also the output to a file.

Using `tee` gives problems with capturing the process id. Hence the `tail` command.

### script

```
#!/bash/bin
set -e

LOG_OUTPUT="output.log"
LOG_RESOURCES="resources.log"

PYTHON_CODE="
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import time

arr = np.zeros(1000)

print('start', datetime.now(), flush=True)
for ii in range(5000000):  # work
    arr += 1
    
print('break start', datetime.now(), flush=True)
time.sleep(3)  # break
print('break end', datetime.now(), flush=True)

for ii in range(5000000):  # work
    arr += 1
print('end', datetime.now(), flush=True)
"

rm -f ${LOG_OUTPUT}
rm -f ${LOG_RESOURCES}

log_process () {
  while ps -p $1 > /dev/null
  do
    top -p $1 -b -d 1 -n 1 >> $LOG_RESOURCES
    printf "\n\n" >> $LOG_RESOURCES
    sleep 1.
  done
}

python -c "${PYTHON_CODE}" >> ${LOG_OUTPUT} 2>&1 &  # run python in background
PID_PYTHON=$!  # python process id
echo "PID_PYTHON=${PID_PYTHON}"
tail -f ${LOG_OUTPUT} &  # show output on terminal
log_process $PID_PYTHON  # log needed resources to file
```

### terminal output

```
$ bash monitor_python_script.sh 
PID_PYTHON=6807
start 2023-05-04 10:08:56.510581
end 2023-05-04 10:09:01.770897
break start 2023-05-04 10:09:04.280212
break end 2023-05-04 10:09:07.283365
end 2023-05-04 10:09:14.875994
```

### log file output: `output.log`

```
start 2023-05-04 10:08:56.510581
break start 2023-05-04 10:09:04.280212
break end 2023-05-04 10:09:07.283365
end 2023-05-04 10:09:14.875994
```

### log file resources: `resources.log`

```
top - 10:08:56 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.08, 0.10, 0.09
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 16.1 us, 10.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 73.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29084.9 free,   3086.8 used,   2072.7 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30686.5 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 R 100.0   0.1   0:00.38 python


top - 10:08:57 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.08, 0.10, 0.09
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 14.6 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 84.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29083.8 free,   3087.9 used,   2072.7 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30685.5 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 R 100.0   0.1   0:01.53 python


top - 10:08:58 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.23, 0.13, 0.10
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 15.2 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 84.4 id,  0.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29083.9 free,   3087.8 used,   2072.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30685.6 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 R 100.0   0.1   0:02.69 python


top - 10:09:00 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.23, 0.13, 0.10
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 14.3 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 85.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29083.1 free,   3088.5 used,   2072.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30684.9 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 R 100.0   0.1   0:03.85 python


top - 10:09:01 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.23, 0.13, 0.10
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 14.3 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 85.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29083.3 free,   3088.3 used,   2072.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30685.1 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 R 100.0   0.1   0:05.01 python


top - 10:09:02 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.23, 0.13, 0.10
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7.1 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.5 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29096.4 free,   3075.2 used,   2072.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30698.1 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 R 100.0   0.1   0:06.17 python


top - 10:09:03 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.29, 0.14, 0.11
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7.1 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29096.4 free,   3075.2 used,   2072.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30698.1 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 R 100.0   0.1   0:07.32 python


top - 10:09:04 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.29, 0.14, 0.11
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29096.9 free,   3074.7 used,   2072.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30698.6 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 S   0.0   0.1   0:08.05 python


top - 10:09:05 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.29, 0.14, 0.11
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.5 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29096.6 free,   3074.9 used,   2073.0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30698.3 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 S   0.0   0.1   0:08.05 python


top - 10:09:07 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.29, 0.14, 0.11
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.4 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29087.0 free,   3084.6 used,   2072.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30688.8 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 S   0.0   0.1   0:08.05 python


top - 10:09:08 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.29, 0.14, 0.11
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7.6 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29086.5 free,   3085.1 used,   2072.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30688.4 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 R 100.0   0.1   0:08.95 python


top - 10:09:09 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.35, 0.16, 0.11
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8.1 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 91.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29086.7 free,   3084.9 used,   2072.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30688.6 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 R 100.0   0.1   0:10.11 python


top - 10:09:10 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.35, 0.16, 0.11
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29087.0 free,   3084.5 used,   2072.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30688.9 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 R 100.0   0.1   0:11.27 python


top - 10:09:11 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.35, 0.16, 0.11
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8.1 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 91.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29086.5 free,   3085.1 used,   2072.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30688.4 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 R 100.0   0.1   0:12.43 python


top - 10:09:12 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.35, 0.16, 0.11
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7.1 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29086.3 free,   3085.3 used,   2072.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30688.2 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 R 100.0   0.1   0:13.59 python


top - 10:09:13 up  1:47,  0 users,  load average: 0.40, 0.17, 0.12
Tasks:   1 total,   1 running,   0 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8.1 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 91.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  34244.4 total,  29086.2 free,   3085.3 used,   2072.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.  30688.1 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   6807 user      20   0  532700  28592  14444 R 100.0   0.1   0:14.74 python
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fabien Sanglard](https://fabiensanglard.net/about/index.html) built a tool for [exploring the Linux command-line space time](https://fabiensanglard.net/st/index.html). It analyzes how many threads/processes, how much time, and how much memory a certain commandline used. You can learn more about it, on the [blog article where he announced the tool](https://fabiensanglard.net/st/index.html).

It was originally called `st` but was later renamed to `ste` to avoid name clashes with another unrelated project. It's [source is available on GitHub](https://github.com/fabiensanglard/st).

Here's a sample output:

```
$ sudo ste clang -o hello hello.c

EXEC: [clang /home/leaf/hello.cc]
EXEC: [/usr/lib/llvm-14/bin/clang -cc1 ...]
EXEC: [/usr/bin/ld ...]
Num threads = 3
Num process = 3
Max PSS: 127,156,224 bytes
Walltime: 221ms - user-space: 136ms - kernel-space: 69ms

127┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
   ┃                                                                                     ┃
   ┃                                                                                     ┃
   ┃                                                          █████████████              ┃
   ┃            █                    ██████████████████████████████████████              ┃
   ┃            █           ███████████████████████████████████████████████              ┃
   ┃            █         █████████████████████████████████████████████████      █ ████  ┃
   ┃            █  ████████████████████████████████████████████████████████  ████████████┃
   ┫            ███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████ █████████████┃
   ┃           ██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████┃
   ┃          ███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████┃
   ┃        █████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████┃
   ┃      ███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████┃
   ┃    █████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████┃
   ┃   ██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████┃
   ┃█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████┃
0MB┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
   0ms                                                                                 221
```