# Monitor single process to logfile perodicly

Tags: networking, logs, memory, monitoring, cpu

Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554/how-to-monitor-cpu-memory-usage-of-a-single-process) question, I would like to log the performance of a specific process, with a frequency of say one second, to a `csv` (comma separated value) log file.

Something like:

```
timestamp(unix),cpu_activity(%),mem_usage(B),network_activity(B)
1355407327,24.6,7451518,345
1355407328,27.6,7451535,12
1355407329,31.6,7451789,467
...
```

Comment: what value you want in network_activity ?

Comment: Oh, yeah it should probably be `network_rx`, and `network_tx` or so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried to get rx_bytes and tx_bytes but no luck, other things is working.. So you can use below script for the same

```
#!/bin/bash

# /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes
# /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes

Process="$1"

[[ -z $2 ]] && InterVal=1 || InterVal=$2

show_help() {
cat <<_EOF
Usage :
        $0  <ProcessName>  <Interval (Default 1s)>
_EOF
}

Show_Process_Stats() {
pgrep "${Process}" >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "Error: Process($1) it not Running.."; exit 1;};
while :
do
    # timestamp(unix),cpu_activity(%),mem_usage(B),network_activity(B)
    timestamp=$(date +%s)
    read cpu_activty mem_usage < <( ps --no-headers -o %cpu,rssize  -C "${Process}" )   
    echo "${timestamp}","${cpu_activty}","${mem_usage}"
    sleep $InterVal
done
}


Main() {
case $1 in
        ""|-h|--help)
                      show_help
                      ;;
                     *)
                      Show_Process_Stats
                      ;;
esac                      
}


Main $*
```

Comment: Great job! Of course, ps is the way to go.

Comment: I'll get back to you if I figure out the network tx, rx

Answer (score 0):

what calculation should do with rx and tx ? i tried below things , please check and let us know what you want to accomplish.

```
#!/bin/bash

# /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes
# /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes

Process="$1"

[[ -z $2 ]] && InterVal=1 || InterVal=$2

show_help() {
cat <<_EOF
Usage :
                $0  <ProcessName>  <Interval (Default 1s)>
_EOF
}

Show_Process_Stats() {
pgrep "${Process}" >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "Error: Process($1) it not Running.."; exit 1;};
old_rx=0
old_tx=0
echo "timestamp,cpu_activty,mem_usage,rx_bytes,tx_bytes"
while :
do
        # timestamp(unix),cpu_activity(%),mem_usage(B),network_activity(B)
        timestamp=$(date +%s)
        raw_rx_bytes=$(< /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes )
        raw_tx_bytes=$(< /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes )
        rx_bytes=$(( $raw_rx_bytes - $old_rx ))
        tx_bytes=$(( $raw_tx_bytes - $old_tx ))
        read cpu_activty mem_usage < <( ps --no-headers -o %cpu,rssize  -C "${Process}" )
        echo "${timestamp}","${cpu_activty}","${mem_usage}","${rx_bytes}","${tx_bytes}"
        old_rx=${raw_rx_bytes}
        old_tx=${raw_tx_bytes}
        sleep $InterVal
done
}


Main() {
case $1 in
                ""|-h|--help)
                                          show_help
                                          ;;
                                         *)
                                          Show_Process_Stats
                                          ;;
esac
}


Main $*
```