# What is the difference between ps and top command?

Tags: process, top, ps, command, process-management

What is the difference between `ps` and `top` command ? I see that both can display information about running processes .  Which one should be used when ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`top` is mostly used interactively (try reading man page or pressing "h"  while `top` is running) and `ps` is designed for non-interactive use (scripts, extracting some information with shell pipelines etc.)

Answer (score 14):

`top` allows you display of process statistics continuously until stopped vs. `ps` which gives you a single snapshot.

Answer (score 11):

Another point:

`ps` - (Process Status) -  It reports a snapshot of current processes.
`top` (Table Of Processes) -  is a task manager program displays information about CPU and memory utilization.

Comment: I thought, the name `top`, didn't make any sense until I saw your answer.

Comment: BTW - `ps` - _**P**rocesses **S**tatus_

Answer (score 5):

`top` enables you to see your processes ordered by the amount of processor power they use.
`ps` enables you to see all your processes, or just the processes used by certain users, for example `root` or yourself.

`top` should be used to see which processes are most active, `ps` could be used to see which processes you (or any other user) are running currently.

for more information about how to use `top` and `ps`, run `man top` or `man ps` in your terminal ;)

Answer (score 3):

For CPU usage, `ps` displays average CPU usage over the lifetime of the process as it is instantaneous and would always be 0% or 100%. `top` gives a more instantaneous look at it from averaging over recent polls.

More information here:
[Top and ps not showing the same cpu result](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58539/top-and-ps-not-showing-the-same-cpu-result)

Comment: The average CPU usage (`%CPU`) could be anything between 0 and 100% (inclusive). According to the `procps-ng` man page, *It will not add up to 100% unless you are lucky.*