# Difference between top and ps output

Tags: ps, top

I have seen [What is the difference between ps and top command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62176/15760) but I think my question is unrelated.
My system is Lubuntu 13.04.
I run `top` in one lxterminal window and `ps -eo %c%C --sort -%cpu | head -6` in another.
I play a YouTube video in Firefox.
Very quickly, the values for `plugin-container` in the `top` screen "stabilize" whereas the values I get by repeatedly issuing `ps -eo %c%C --sort -%cpu | head -6` rise slowly.
Similarly, when I close the Firefox tab that was playing the YouTube video, the plugin-container entry in `top` goes away promptly but it lingers on in the output of `ps -eo %c%C --sort -%cpu | head -6`, declining slowly as can be seen below:

```
    [04:43 PM] ~ $ ps -eo %c%C --sort -%cpu | head -6
    COMMAND         %CPU
    plugin-containe 21.5
    firefox          4.9
    Xorg             1.6
    lxpanel          0.2
    dropbox          0.2
    [04:43 PM] ~ $ ps -eo %c%C --sort -%cpu | head -6
    COMMAND         %CPU
    plugin-containe 21.3
    firefox          4.9
    Xorg             1.6
    lxpanel          0.2
    dropbox          0.2
    [04:43 PM] ~ $ ps -eo %c%C --sort -%cpu | head -6
    COMMAND         %CPU
    plugin-containe 20.9
    firefox          4.9
    Xorg             1.6
    lxpanel          0.2
    dropbox          0.2
    [04:43 PM] ~ $ ps -eo %c%C --sort -%cpu | head -6
    COMMAND         %CPU
    plugin-containe 20.2
    firefox          4.9
    Xorg             1.6
    lxpanel          0.2
    dropbox          0.2
    [04:44 PM] ~ $ ps -eo %c%C --sort -%cpu | head -6
    COMMAND         %CPU
    plugin-containe 20.0
    firefox          4.9
    Xorg             1.6
    lxpanel          0.2
    dropbox          0.2
    [04:44 PM] ~ $ ps -eo %c%C --sort -%cpu | head -6
    COMMAND         %CPU
    plugin-containe 18.9
    firefox          4.9
    Xorg             1.6
    lxpanel          0.2
    dropbox          0.2
    [04:44 PM] ~ $
```

`plugin-container` does eventually go away, but how should I modify `ps -eo %c%C --sort -%cpu | head -6` to make it go away quicker?

(All this is done on a Dell 1545 Core2Duo laptop.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing apples to oranges. `top` is displaying what proportion of your computer's CPU power that process used during the last sampling interval (a few seconds, usually). `ps`, with `%C`, is displaying what proportion of the time that process was running over that process's lifetime. Because of the way process statistics are gathered, any command that does display CPU usage over the past few seconds has to run for a few seconds, and `ps` doesn't have any options to do that. You can however use `top` in batch mode, `top -b -n 2 -d 0.001`. It will pause gathering data, and then give its listing over STDOUT. This will allow you to parse `top` output or use it in scripts.