# Commands 'top' and 'ps' show different values for priority - why?

Tags: linux, command-line

`top` shows a priority of **20** for most processes, including (for example **firefox-bin**).

Whilst `ps -o pid,lwp,pri,nice,start,stat,bsdtime,cmd,comm -C firefox-bin` shows:

```
  PID   LWP PRI  NI  STARTED STAT   TIME CMD                         COMMAND
 9798  9798  19   0 14:03:47 Sl     2:17 /opt/firefox/firefox        firefox-bin
```

Since both top & ps are ancient commands, this seems unlikely to be a bug. Why the discrepancy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between ps and top command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62176/what-is-the-difference-between-ps-and-top-command)

Comment: @taliezin, that suggested duplicate says nothing about the priority value displayed in each command.

Comment: The **ps** command displays a snapshot of typically just one process, whilst **top** is typically used to repeatedly display many processes and their effect on machine load.

Comment: @user4556274, I see, so [this](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/issues/111) might be helpful.

Comment: So its a reported issue? It seems a process can have many priorities...

Comment: @JeremyBoden, there is also an explanation / answer.

Answer (score 4):

Linux priorities range from 0 to 139. You can see the true priority of a process by looking in the *sched* file in the process' */proc/* subdirectory. For example, Firefox on my system has a process ID of 84163. So, if I run *grep ^prio /proc/84163/sched,* it tells me the priority is 120. This is the default priority in Linux. Real-time priorities range from 0 to 99 and users can assign priorities from 100 to 139. However, *ps* tells me the priority of Firefox is 80 and *top* tells me it's 20. Why are all three different? According to [this page,](https://learning.lpi.org/en/learning-materials/101-500/103/103.6/103.6_01/) the priority given by ps ranges from -40 to 99. So, to get the real priority, add 40 to it. The top command subtracts 100 from each priority. So, to get the true priority in top, add 100 to it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `top` shows priority as `20 + nice value` but `ps` shows `19 - nice value` so both shows priority as value from 0 to 39 but in `top` 0 means highest priority but in `ps` 39 means highest priority.

I'm not sure why is this different and it is possible this is a bug in `ps` because its man page says "Higher number means lower priority."

Comment: If I use `ps -o pri` then this statement is also true, but as @user431397 points out, I am using the wrong kind of priority.

Comment: Interesting, ps manpage mentions only `pri` (and `rprio` for real time priority) not `priority` option/column.