# Average CPU utilization of a process

Tags: ps, top

I am trying to conduct some experiments for determining what the CPU utilization of my process is. I am familiar with the `top` and `ps` commands. Which would be a better solution for getting the average CPU utilization of my process throughout the entire time? From [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58539/top-and-ps-not-showing-the-same-cpu-result?newreg=5f4dbd9400b241369b1c98a0df04cb7f) question it seems like ps would be the best way. Would using top periodically to record stats and averaging the results be more precise?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `gprof` might be what you are looking for. It'll help with debugging to figure out how much time is spent in a function.

You might also want to check out this stack exchange answer: [How does “top” calculate CPU usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15993886/1036361)

Comment: I'm not looking to profile my app. I just want to show what the overall avg CPU utilization for the process is on running it for an hour

Comment: @AndroidDev93 I think the stack exchange answer is what you're looking for then. Just have a separate program\script constantly read from /proc