# Sleep while process uses more than n% CPU

Tags: bash

I am on macOS. I want to write a bash script which pauses for 0.5 seconds (i.e. sleeps) while a certain process (which I know by command name only) uses more than, say 5% CPU. I could

`pgrep command_name`

and then

`ps -p PID -o %cpu | tail -1 | cut -c 3-5`

to get the CPU usage and use this number in a while loop. Can this be done more elegantly (ideally in one line of code)?

Comment: Sure you want to use CPU usage from `ps`? I.e. `man ps | less +/'NOTES'` and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58539/140633

Comment: Happy to use `top`. But I still can't do it elegantly.

Comment: `pidof` might also be a good tool instead of `pgrep`.

Comment: by the way, what's the process you're watching there? (And: I don't know how or how much OS X smooths the CPU load, but this looks like something that might go wrong when your script happens to look in the wrong moments, when the process is e.g. limited by IO load)

Comment: I want to watch the app Apple Compressor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it simpler by using command substitution:

```
ps -p $(pgrep firefox) -o %cpu | tail -1 | cut -c 3-5
```

I am afraid I don't have a mac to test on, so the following might not work on your system, but on Linux, we can use `%cpu=` to avoid printing the header:

```
$ ps -p $(pgrep firefox) -o %cpu 
%CPU
23.3
$ ps -p $(pgrep firefox) -o %cpu= 
23.3
```

Which means that `ps -p $(pgrep firefox) -o %cpu=` is enough to give you the number only.

Comment: Works indeed. Many thanks!

Comment: @220284 you're welcome. Out of curiosity, which one worked? Does the `=` trick work with your `ps`?

Comment: `ps -p $(pgrep firefox) -o %cpu=` works on macOS as well

Comment: Ah good, I was afraid that was a GNU thing. Thanks!