# How to stream top snapshot into file?

Tags: top

Is there any way to persist the snapshot of `top` at that given moment into a file?

I tried

```
top > top.out
```

but the contents were nothing like top in STDOUT:

```
^[[H^[[2J^[(B^[[mtop - 16:09:49 up 18 days, 21:46,  4 users,  load average: 2.00, 1.90, 1.87^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[[K
Tasks:^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m 286 ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mtotal,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m   1 ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mrunning,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m 285 ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49msleeping,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m   0 ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mstopped,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m   0 ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mzombie^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[[K
Cpu(s):^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  5.9%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mus,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  0.1%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49msy,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  0.0%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mni,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m 93.5%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mid,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  0.3%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mwa,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  0.0%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mhi,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  0.1%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49msi,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  0.0%^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mst^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[[K
Mem: ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m 64322524k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mtotal,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m 46529492k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mused,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m 17793032k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mfree,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m   141304k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mbuffers^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[[K
Swap:^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  6289436k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mtotal,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m      696k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mused,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m  6288740k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mfree,^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[(B^[[m 15289220k ^[(B^[[m^[[39;49mcached^[(B^[[m^[[39;49m^[[K
^[[6;1H
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that `top` by defaults includes ANSI/VT100 escape codes. In this case, it seems like what you want is only the "raw" text output (i.e. not information that some text should be bold etc etc). Luckily, `top` has built-in support for this mode of operation, called "batch mode" in their documentation.

From the top man page (`man top`):

```
-n : Number of iterations limit as:  -n number
     Specifies the maximum number of iterations, or frames, top should
     produce before ending.
-b : Batch mode operation
     Starts  top in 'Batch mode', which could be useful for sending output
     from top to other programs or to a file. In this mode, top will not
     accept input and runs until the iterations limit you've set with
     the '-n' command-line option or until killed.
```

So...

```
top -n 1 -b > top.out
```

For other command-line utilities that do not have a convenient "-b" type switch like top, it might also be done with [ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/). Download, compile, and install. Then you could...

```
top -n 1 | ansifilter > top.out
```