# CPU and Memory usage monitoring for a single process

Tags: process, monitoring, aix

I need to monitor the CPU and Memory usage for a single process in an AIX server. The program runs 3 times a day. I need to find the way to capture statistics within some time intervals, lets say every 10 min.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554/how-to-monitor-cpu-memory-usage-of-a-single-process

Answer (score 1):

I suggest collecting overall system statistics with [`nmon`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/nmon.htm) and parsing them with [`nmon-analyzer`](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-nmon_analyser) or [`nmon2rrd`](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Power%20Systems/page/nmon2rrd) - even if it's just for one process. Having something to correlate with is useful. [`svmon`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.prftools/idprftools_svmon.htm) can also be used to monitor memory usage.

Here are some good articles on process and system monitoring for AIX:

- [Optimizing AIX 7 memory performance: Part 2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix7memoryoptimize2/index.html) - Monitoring memory usage (developerWorks);
- [Analyze memory usage on AIX](http://www.unix.com/aix/217091-howto-analyze-memory-usage-aix-aka-svmon-101-a.html) (UNIX.COM);
- [Practical Guide to AIX: Memory](http://aix4admins.blogspot.com/2011/09/memory-leak-caused-by-program-that.html) (AIX for System Administrators);
- [AIX Performance Tools](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Power%20Systems/page/Other%20Performance%20Tools) (developerWorks Power Community);

Answer (score 0):

I assume aix works like gnu/linux.
Create a file in /etc/cron.d/. Let's call it 'monitor' change the `grep processname` part to your processname

```
# +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
# |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *  user    command to be executed
*/10 *  *  *  *  root    ps aux | grep processname >>/var/log/mylog.log
```

add the following line to /var/log/mylog.log

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
```

if you don't have root, you can start crontab -e as user omit the username root before ps aux, and instead of redirecting the output to /var/log/ you should use $HOME/.

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving an idea and not a complete script. You need to modify to suit your requirements.

To monitor the CPU usage and memory usage, the command that you use is `ps`. I believe `-C` and `-o` flags are supportedin **AIX** server. Nevertheless, you could figure out the corresponding syntax from `man ps` in your machine.

```
ps -C program_name -o %cpu,%mem
```

Now, to make it execute every 10 minutes for 6 times in the server, I would put the below script. I assume you need to monitor once in every 10 minutes for an hour or so.

```
i=6
filename=$(echo memory_monitoring_`date +%F_%T`)
touch $filename
while [ $i -ge 1 ]
do
    sleep 600 #sleep for 10 minutes. 
    ps -C program_name -o %cpu,%mem >> "$filename"
    i=$((i-1)) 
done
```

So basically with the above script, I create a new file every time I need to monitor the memory. After that, I execute the script for 1 hour which is why you see `i` is set to 6. `sleep 600` is for monitoring the memory every 10 minutes.

If you need optimizations, you could add a `mail` command to email yourself the created file so that you could use it for auditing purposes.

Setting up a `cron` job is fairly straight forward and you could find numerous online tutorials that could help you out.

Comment: Ramesh, '-C'  flag did  not work,  so I used $ps -ef | grep 'process_name'. It returned three different PIDs for the  same processes. I do not know which id corresponds to which process.  How would I find unique PID I  need?