# Virtual CPU utilization(multi core CPU)- Identify the process

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, top, cpu-usage

I am in a road block and trying to understand the below.
Red hat Linux has been installed in a Intel Xeon CPU. We have a 6 core virtual CPU's. I am trying to find out which job is consuming more of the CPU(overall CPU utilization) combined of all the virtual core CPU's. Particularly need to find out which of the DataStage job running is eating more of the CPU. Have tried the Top command with all options, but not getting a correct answer say for example this job has consumed 60% of the all CPU's at 3 PM today. Can anyone help me?

Comment: check out -- http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554/how-to-monitor-cpu-memory-usage-of-a-single-process

Answer (score 0):

I think `pidstat` is what you need. For example:

`pidstat -C java 3` will show CPU usage of process java, every 3 seconds

`pidstat 3` will show active processes and the CPU usage per CPU, per process every 3 seconds.