# How to remove 'top' command's header?

Tags: linux, top

[image]

I have top as above, and would like to remove header.

I tried to look into its sourcecode but can't find what should be changed to remove its header, trying to modify and create a patch.

Comment: Related SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234401/removing-header-from-top-output

Comment: Not quite right, I need to start top that doesn't have header, in your link, the output doesn't have header.

Comment: https://github.com/mmalecki/procps/blob/master/top.c#L2101 seems to be the area

Comment: It's weird when I try to re-build package with `makepkg` - I use archlinux. After build, modified `top.c` file always restore to its original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with below command it worked fine for me

command

```
top | sed -n '/PID/,$p'|sed '/PID/d'
```

output

```
top | sed -n '/PID/,$p'|sed '/PID/d'
 5696 praveen   20   0 1063064 301524 124384 S   5.0  5.0   3:47.86 chrome      
 2064 praveen   20   0 1349120 240216 125140 S   3.3  4.0   5:15.39 chrome      
 2131 praveen   20   0  657804 177656 124292 S   3.3  2.9   3:13.29 chrome      
 1317 praveen   20   0  372280  66304  42424 R   1.3  1.1   1:57.22 Xorg        
 1462 praveen   20   0 3843312 198160  72588 S   0.7  3.3   4:08.08 gnome-shell 
 2675 praveen   20   0  732392  39200  28476 S   0.3  0.6   0:19.70 gnome-term+ 
 4947 praveen   20   0  763008 119988  75828 S   0.3  2.0   0:06.20 chrome      
 6522 praveen   20   0   49016   3856   3232 R   0.3  0.1   0:00.15 top         
    1 root      20   0  225528   9432   6772 S   0.0  0.2   0:06.29 systemd     
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd    
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+ 
    6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_+ 
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.04 ksoftirqd/0 
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:03.76 rcu_sched   
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh      
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/0 
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 watchdo
```

Comment: Can we keep texts: `PID` `USER` ..etc but remove background only?

Answer (score -1):

To remove the background only, just press <kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>T</kbd> and up/down until you match the background, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and <kbd>W</kbd> to persist the new settings in your config file.

Comment: This solution does not _remove_ the _header_ as indicated by OP on my Linux system. It does indeed change the header ABOVE the header BAR that OP wants removed, but not the bar itslef as indicated by the original question. For this reason, downvoted.